# Find real numbers c and d from $\frac{1}{a+bi}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, both not 0. Find real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{a+bi} = c + di$$

I am not really sure what the question is asking me to do. Am I supposed to represent $c$ and $di$ both in terms of $a$ and $b$ since $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?

I multiplied the fraction by its conjugate, but that didn't give me any hints.

$$\frac{1}{a+bi} \bigg( \frac{a-bi}{a-bi}\bigg) = \frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$$

A nudge in the correct direction would be helpful, thanks

Comment: You're on the right track.  Set the real and imaginary parts of $\dfrac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$ and $c+di$ equal

Comment: you are almost done, just get the real (c) and imaginary (d) parts of $\frac{a-i b}{a^2+b^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i=c+di.
$$
Hence
$$
c=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\,\, \text{ and }\,\,d=-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}.
$$

Comment: Oh, and I think the reason you can do this is because both sides of the equation are now in the format $(a + bi)$ so thats why you can get values of $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You compare the respective real and imaginary parts of both sides.